# Significant push notification delay

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I just started implementing a push notifications on my app. Apple accepts my notification (my stream_socket_client to sandbox returns true). And my message is of the form:

```
{ "aps" : { "alert" : "This is the alert", "badge" : 1, "sound" : "bingbong.aiff" }
```

Yesterday I send several notifications in the morning but none arrived on my phone. That afternoon, I received one notification. Since I received a notification, I'm assuming my code is correct, but I'm surprised the notification took hours...

**Is it usual to have such delay (and loss of notifications)?**

Comment: I had this once, It took the whole night to reach the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens but not usual, push notifications is unreliable and it is not guaranteed of delivery according to [apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9):

> Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not guaranteed. It is
>   not intended to deliver data to your app, only to notify the user that
>   there is new data available.

check this question: [How much delay of ios push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204767/how-much-delay-of-ios-push-notification)