# Receiving push notifications with high delay

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, parse-platform

I have implemented push notifications using Parse SDK and I am testing this with two devices. i.e iPhone and iPad.

Whenever my Rails server fires a push notification, in parse dashboard it is showing the status as DONE. But I am getting the notifications after 30 minutes and sometimes more. Hence it is taking so much time to debug the notifications handling code.

Is there any specific way to get notifications immediately?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204776/2857130

Comment: @staticVoidMan If you think it's a duplicate, vote to close it as a duplicate, don't just add a link to the duplicate in the comments.

Comment: did you test via the sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

No chance at all. The apns service depends on different things, your network connectivity, the apns server from apple and others. Apple says that there is no guarantee that a push notification will be delivered inside a specific time.