# APN Push Notifications coming in bursts

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing an iOS app and I'm facing this weird bug where the push notifications come in bursts.

Basically, let's say I send 10 push notifications with APN from a server (my logs show that the push notification sends), but I don't receive it until some arbitray time later, when I receive all 10 notifications at once.

I've double-checked my app-side code and have also tried re-generating/re-uploading the p12 certs and after looking around here, I haven't managed to find anything either./

Would anyone be able to shed some light on this? Any help is appreciated!

*UPDATE: my logs show that every time the server sends a push notification, it also sends a 'apple sandbox notification' simultaneously, but I'm notsure what that is

Comment: From my experience (and i think somewhere in Apple's documentation - but i can't find it right now) you can't be sure that any of your Push Notifcations are getting delivered in time. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204767/how-much-delay-of-ios-push-notification

Comment: APNS is a best effort service. There's no guarantee when or even if the message will be delivered to a device. Also worth noting that if a device isn't reachable, only the most recent notification will be cached for delivery. All the other messages that failed to deliver will be discarded.

Comment: Now you have a problem which may be from the server side or the mobile side, I recommend you to use a third party push service like [NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher), it talks to APNs directly and helps you to send a custom payload for a specific certificate and device token.
If you got the push instantly then the problem is in the server side otherwise try to check the mobile side.

Comment: If nothing from the above mentioned solutions works. Try the same steps with Mobile internet in place of wifi. I was facing similar issues and this thing solved it.

Comment: Please update your question with the notification payload